# Systemd causing multiple supervisor processes

Tags: init.d, systemd, supervisord, systemctl

I'm having a problem narrowing down where the issue is for my supervisor configuration that causes a program to be duplicated.

I'm running a Python Tornado Web Server through an Nginx reverse proxy. I think the problem is more related to supervisor, though.

> **/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf**

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock
chmod=0700

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor           
logfile_maxbytes=50MB                           
logfile_backups=5                               
loglevel=error                                  

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

> **/etc/supervisor/conf.d/tornado.conf**

```
[program:tornado]
numprocs = 4
numprocs_start = 8000
process_name = %(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
directory=/home/username/webapp
environment=PATH="/home/username/.virtualenvs/tornado_env/bin"
command = python server.py --port=%(process_num)s
user=www-data
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/webapp/%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d.log
loglevel=info
```

As you can see `numprocs = 4`, but my confusion comes from this after just restarting the server.

> **ps -aux | egrep "supervisor|python"**

```
root       399  0.1  2.6  14496  9584 ?        Ss   15:48   0:03 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
www-data   410  0.1  3.9  16872 14200 ?        S    15:48   0:02 python server.py --port=8002
www-data   411  0.1  3.9  16872 14180 ?        S    15:48   0:02 python server.py --port=8003
www-data   412  0.1  3.9  16872 14124 ?        S    15:48   0:02 python server.py --port=8000
www-data   413  0.1  3.9  16872 14180 ?        S    15:48   0:02 python server.py --port=8001
www-data   489  0.0  3.0  16872 11024 ?        S    15:49   0:00 python server.py --port=8003
www-data   490  0.0  3.1  16872 11228 ?        S    15:49   0:00 python server.py --port=8000
www-data   491  0.0  3.1  16872 11244 ?        S    15:49   0:00 python server.py --port=8002
www-data   492  0.0  3.0  16872 11192 ?        S    15:49   0:00 python server.py --port=8001
```

There are 8 Python processes, but supervisor only knows about 4. What else do I look for?

> **sudo supervisorctl status**

```
tornado:tornado_8000             RUNNING    pid 412, uptime 0:36:03
tornado:tornado_8001             RUNNING    pid 413, uptime 0:36:03
tornado:tornado_8002             RUNNING    pid 410, uptime 0:36:05
tornado:tornado_8003             RUNNING    pid 411, uptime 0:36:04
```

---

**UPDATE**: Somehow running `supervisor` and `systemd` is spawning a duplicate configuration. So now my question is do I disable the `supervisor` service and if so, then what else is causing it to start?

> **sudo systemctl status supervisor**

```
● supervisor.service - LSB: Start/stop supervisor
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/supervisor)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2015-12-23 15:48:45 CST; 1h 31min ago
  Process: 305 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/supervisor start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/supervisor.service
           ├─399 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
           ├─489 python server.py --port=8003
           ├─490 python server.py --port=8000
           ├─491 python server.py --port=8002
           └─492 python server.py --port=8001
```

Comment: Just as an aside, if you have systemd, why on earth are you still using supervisor (which is redundant)?

Answer (score 1):

Upon further investigation, the problem was actually my Python Tornado Server. It was forking one process per CPU, which confuses me on a single core Raspberry Pi, but whatever.

So, the output of the commands above are valid; there are no "duplicates" from supervisor or Systemd. The problem was more related to lifecycle management of these processes by supervisor, i.e. start, stop, reload.

When I would stop it before, the forked processes would remain active, so when I went to restart supervisor, I would then get a total of 4 + 8 = 12 processes.

The fix was to add this line to my `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/tornado.conf`.

```
stopasgroup=true
```

For which [the documentation](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html) reads

> If true, the flag causes supervisor to send the stop signal to the whole process group and implies `killasgroup` is true. This is useful for programs, such as Flask in debug mode, that do not propagate stop signals to their children, leaving them orphaned.